# How do I write a generic recursive function that takes a CollectionType in Swift?

Tags: swift2

How would you create a generic function to process a CollectionType in Swift? For example, I want something that boils down to this:

```
func f<C: CollectionType>(list: C) {
    if list.isEmpty {
        return
    }
    else {
        f(list.dropFirst()) // causes error
    }
}
```

This causes an error because SubSequence might not be a CollectionType: **Cannot invoke 'f' with an argument list of type '(C.SubSequence)'**

I tried working around it by constraining the SubSequence type like this:

`<C: CollectionType where C.SubSequence: CollectionType>`

I get the same error, though. Any suggestions on how to write a generic recursive function for CollectionType?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your error, you can transform a SubSequence into an array with the `Array` initializer:

```
func f<C: CollectionType>(list: C) {
    if list.isEmpty {
        return
    }
    else {
        f(Array(list.dropFirst()))
    }
}
```

Comment: This does a copy of the array on every iteration. Ouch.

Comment: @Alexander Please post a better solution. :)

Comment: @Alexander Excellent, thanks! Now let's hope OP unaccepts my answer so that I can delete it... but given that they are "Last seen Oct 28 '15" it's rather unlikely. :p

Comment: That's alright, hopefully it helps people who land on this

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that doesn't require copying the storage in a new array with every iteration:

```
func f<C: CollectionType
    where C.SubSequence: CollectionType,
    C.SubSequence == C.SubSequence.SubSequence>(c: C) {

    guard let first = c.first else { return }

    print(first)
    f(c.dropFirst())
}
```

In Swift 3:

```
func f<C>(_ c: C) where 
    C: Collection,
    C.SubSequence: Collection,
    C.SubSequence == C.SubSequence.SubSequence {

    guard !c.isEmpty else { return }
    f(c.dropFirst())
}

f([1, 2, 3])
```